# Calculations in php or mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

I have come across a few questions on the same lines but none exactly the same.

Which one is better, performing some basic calculations in PHP after getting results from MySql (by joining a few tables) or physically having another column in MySql which stores the total while inserting a new row and then retrieving it.

E.g: A product sold:

```
Item         Price       Quantity      Discount
Item 1        55           100           10%
```

The above is a sales table, the price column is joint from the items table. Based on the above question either we can use PHP to fetch results, perform `Price X Quantity X 0.10` or we our table can look like the following:

```
Item         Price       Quantity      Discount   Amount
Item 1        55           100           10%        4950
```

Now which is the better way of doing such a simple task?

Similar Question:
[Doing Calculations in MySql vs PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449072/doing-calculations-in-mysql-vs-php)

Comment: [Doing calculations in MySQL vs PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449072/doing-calculations-in-mysql-vs-php)

Comment: @DanLee, that is performing calculations in MySql, mine is storing the value in another column.

Comment: If you add another column and you'd have to care about 2 tables when updating I'd stick to the joining solution. Because this can get messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no blanket rule for all situations.  Many factors affect the performance and efficiency of websites.  So there's no single 'Best'.

If you look at something like Magento, it does it both ways.  On the one hand it has a full EAV structure with every piece of data abstracted out and normalised to the nth degree.  On the other hand, it also aggregates pre-calculated values in flat tables for performance reasons.  This includes discount amounts, base prices, tax quantities (in base and chosen currency), etc.  The former situation is best in terms of flexibility and robustness, the flat table is better in terms of performance.

A flat table obviously makes it faster when dealing with bulk calculations, as everything has already been worked out.  But it does, as kernelpanic pointed out, mean that any changes to settings may require a bulk recalculation of every value. In the case of historical data such as order history, you probably won't want to recalculate the actual amounts people ended up paying, but the possibility of having to do so does need to be taken into consideration when determining the best solution.

If performance is paramount and the calculations are expensive to run, then knowing that you may have to refresh the values in bulk from time-to-time allows you to make an informed decision to cache it or not.

But if it's not a performance critical aspect, or the calculations are expensive but not run often, it's cleaner to leave them out of the database as they really belong in the business logic processing part of an application i.e. the code.

Again there is more than one way of defining "best", so it depends on the circumstances.  It is really just a matter of balancing requirements - speed, cleanliness, memory usage, processor requirements, disk space usage, the need to fit into some arbitrary data structure defined by development managers - your decision will need to account for these factors.

Without a real-world problem to address, speculation is really all that can be given.  If you do have a more complex situation, I'd be happy to take a look and offer my thoughts.

edit: From my own observations, a Magento catalog page with flat data and over 200k products loads in about 10 - 20 seconds with no page caching enabled.  When flat data was disabled and the EAV structure was used, it would take minutes.  I'm not at work right now so I don't have my profiling data handy, but it's a testament to the fact that in real world applications there is no single best solution.

Answer (score 2):

The calculations can be performed either by a SQL Query on fetch or after you pull the data down. The SQL solution would be something like

```
SELECT *, ((Price * Quantity) - ((Price * Quantity) * (Discount * .01))) AS Amount 
FROM ...
```

In many ways this is just a personal preference, although when SQL starts getting very complicated I find it messy to work with.

The thing you likely want to avoid is saving the total to the database, unless it is a set amount that will never change. If your total is saved and at some point you change your discount amount or quantity, there's the potential to forget to update the total. If every time you need the total you calculate it from the known variables `(quantity * price - discount)` then the total should always be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the calculations to your SELECT statement.

Sample:

```
SELECT
    ItemID,
    Price,
    Quantity,
    Discount
    Price * Quantity * Discount AS Amount
FROM myTable
```

Or use views to retrieve the data you want and append the calculated values as columns.

This way the calculated values are only valid for the request and you don't have to add additional columns to the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep pre-calculated prices out of the table. This way if your discount changes to say 15% you won't have to recalculate the value for every row each time.

Answer (score 0):

i'll prefer with the upper table structure we can manage all these things by our calculation we should not keep such calculations in DB because we should follow the RDBMS Approach