# Simulate innerjoin in two php array

Tags: php, arrays, inner-join

I have two table in my `phpMyAdmin`.

I want to join this two table, but that tables is very large.

I think if i fetch all table in an array, and another table to another array and join this two array this make my program faster, if is it true, is there any `php` `function` that simulate it?

I have `$arr1` and `$arr2` and i want the `$result`. Also i want to know is it faster than `mysql inner join query`?

```
    $arr1 = array(

    array('id'=>10, 'title' => 'title arr1 1', 'alias' => 'alias arr1 1'),
    array('id'=>20, 'title' => 'title arr1 2', 'alias' => 'alias arr1 2'),
    array('id'=>30, 'title' => 'title arr1 3', 'alias' => 'alias arr1 3'),
    ...

    )


    $arr2 = array(

    array('id'=>1, 'title' => 'title arr2 1', 'alias' => 'alias arr2 1', 'arr1_id' => 30),
    array('id'=>2, 'title' => 'title arr2 2', 'alias' => 'alias arr2 2', 'arr1_id' => 20),
    array('id'=>3, 'title' => 'title arr2 3', 'alias' => 'alias arr2 3', 'arr1_id' => 10),
    ...

    )

    $result = array(

    array
    (
    'id_arr1'=>10, 'title_arr1' => 'title arr1 1', 'alias_arr1' => 'alias arr1 1',
    'id_arr2'=>3, 'title_arr2' => 'title arr2 3', 'alias_arr2' => 'alias arr2 3', 'arr1_id' => 10
    )

    ,

    array
    (
    'id_arr1'=>20, 'title_arr1' => 'title arr1 2', 'alias_arr1' => 'alias arr1 2',
    'id_arr2'=>2, 'title_arr2' => 'title arr2 2', 'alias_arr2' => 'alias arr2 2', 'arr1_id' => 20
    )

    ,

    array
    (
    'id_arr1'=>30, 'title_arr1' => 'title arr1 3', 'alias_arr1' => 'alias arr1 3',
    'id_arr2'=>1, 'title_arr2' => 'title arr2 1', 'alias_arr2' => 'alias arr2 1', 'arr1_id' 

    => 30
        )
    ,
    ...

    )
```

Comment: Did you mean, you want to compare the 2 query result?

Comment: Please, show us the strutter of your arrays and desired "join" result

Comment: I wouldn't think that retrieving a large dataset and processing it with php would be any faster than a join made by the sql server.

Comment: Thanks @bagonyi, but i want to be **sure** is it faster or not?

Comment: can find some help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449072/doing-calculations-in-mysql-vs-php