# Performance - Calculation inside or outside a query?

Tags: php, sql, performance

Is there much in the way of a **performance** difference between having a SUM calculation inside a SQL query vs calculating it in a variable after the query?

Not the greatest example but:

```
IFNULL(AVG((service + value + quality)/3),0) AS business_average
```

vs

```
$average_rating = ($value + $quality + $service) / 3;
```

Only the calculation I'm using is pretty damn extensive - I prefer the variable method as it's more readable, not I can put that aside if the performance is greater via the SQL query

Comment: Have you tried what is faster?

Comment: Some insight here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425756/are-mathematical-functions-in-mysql-faster-than-php

Comment: How would I go about testing? Or do you know of any tutorials I can read up on to find out? :/

Comment: You really need to test it - I've seen more than twenty fold improvements by using SQL math functions over processing in PHP, there is some overhead in processing in PHP and as datasets get larger, that can come into play more and more.

Comment: You mentioned that the example wasn't the greatest.  One reason for that is that the two candidates do different things.  Make sure that your real candidates have the same functionality.

Comment: @DanBracuk, that example was solely given to elaborate what I meant by SQL / PHP variable - If I paste in my actual code the question would be dwarfed by the code